# How to concatenate 4 numpy matrices along the x axis?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, valueerror

I am trying to concatenate 4 numpy matrices along the x axis. Below is the code I have written.

```
print(dt.shape)
print(condition.shape)
print(uc.shape)
print(rt.shape)

x = np.hstack((dt, condition, uc, rt))

print(x.shape)
```

I am getting the following output.

```
(215063, 1)
(215063, 1112)
(215063, 1)
(215063, 1)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

Final output should be

```
(215063, 1115)
```

Comment: With the shapes you show `hstack` should be working.  Something else must be wrong.  Let's check `dtype`.  `type` might also be needed.  And if needed recheck the shapes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

I shall recommend you to use numpy *concatenate*. I used this to merge two images in a single image.It provides you option to concatenate in either of the two axes X and Y. For more info on this visit this [link](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

Comment: `hstack` uses `concatenate`.  It just makes sure all inputs are at least 1d.  So `concatenate` won't take care of his problem.

Comment: I did try concatenate

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK. To confirm it, I performed the following test
on smaller arrays:

```
dt = np.arange(1,6).reshape(-1,1)
condition = np.arange(11,41).reshape(-1,6)
uc = np.arange(71,76).reshape(-1,1)
uc = np.arange(81,86).reshape(-1,1)
print(dt.shape, condition.shape, uc.shape, rt.shape)
x = np.hstack((dt, condition, uc, rt))
print(x.shape)
print(x)
```

and got:

```
(5, 1) (5, 6) (5, 1) (5, 1)
(5, 9)
[[ 1 11 12 13 14 15 16 81 41]
 [ 2 17 18 19 20 21 22 82 42]
 [ 3 23 24 25 26 27 28 83 43]
 [ 4 29 30 31 32 33 34 84 44]
 [ 5 35 36 37 38 39 40 85 45]]
```

So probably there is something wrong with your data.

Attempt to run `np.hstack` on the above set of arrays, dropping
each (one) of them in turn.

If in one case (without some array) the execution succeeds, then
the source of problem is just the array missing in this case.

Then you should look thoroughly at this array and find what is wrong with it.

Comment: It the condition variable